# Where are defined the endpoints in bitcore-lib?

Tags: bitcore

I'm trying to learn more about the `bitpay` and just now, reading about [bitcore-lib](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-lib), but I'm not finding where the addresses and endpoints are specified to connect with the servers.
Someone has an idea where I should find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the server referred to in the question is bitcoind. In case anyone is still looking for these, the rpc and rest endpoints are here https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpc-quick-reference

You can put the addresses/ports in a bitcoin.conf file like this

```
zmqpubrawtx=tcp://127.0.0.1:15371
zmqpubhashblock=tcp://127.0.0.1:15371
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
rpcport=15332
```